# Where do I find the .csv file for the submission after creating it?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cnn, image-classification, colab

I am making a submission of a classificaition problem with CNN on Google Colab. So I have arrived at doing this:

```
subm.to_csv('submission.csv', index=False)
```

so in theory I should have finished. The only problem is that I don't know where to find the newly created csv file.

Can somebody please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are done with Colab instince files saves will not persist. You have to configure saving them to google drive. Try something like this;

> `from google.colab import drive
>   drive.mount('/content/gdrive', force_remount=True)
>   root_dir = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/"
>   base_dir = root_dir + 'fastai-v3/'`

so now you can access and save files to google drive directly.